# How to create random default value in ndb model in GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, python-os

I have a ndb model

```
import os
class ProblemInvite(ndb.Model):
    email = nab.StringProperty(required=True)
    token = ndb.StringProperty(required=True, default=os.urandom(16).encode('hex'))
```

When I create a list of the model, the token is same:

```
import logging
for email in emails:
    problem_invite = ProblemInvite(email=email_address)
    logging.exception(problem_invite.token)
```

The weird thing is, the invite token for each email is same, what's wrong with it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can only be **one** default value for a property type in the datastore at a time. From the [Property Options](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entity-property-reference#options) table:

[image]

So your `os.urandom(16).encode('hex')` expression is evaluated only once. I'm not 100% certain when, but I suspect it'd be at app deployment time - when the datastore models are uploaded.

To address the problem just drop the default value and explicitly specify the property value when you create the entity.

**Side note:** when using default values in ndb models you need to be extra careful at **changing these default values** as the behaviour (i.e. the data returned for the affected properties) **may change** for the entities already existing in the datastore at app deployment/update time.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Make sense.